# Do not copy source file when optimizing using requirejs

Tags: requirejs

When using require.js (r.js) to optimize js code, all js source code are copied to destination directory(dir property).

Is there a way (some configuration) to prevent requirejs to copy source files?

Answer (score 10):

If you add `removeCombined: true` to your r.js build config the optimizer will remove (essentially not copy) all source files that were combined into your output module(s).

Alternately, if you are referring to source files that are not part of the requireJS build at all, try using `fileExclusionRegExp: /^\./` in your config.

See the [example full r.js config file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As rharper mentioned you have to use this property:

```
fileExclusionRegExp
```

For example if you use cssmin to concat/minify your files and don't want requirejs to move your stylesheets, and if you have let's say another folder `foo` you can use:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /css|foo/
```

to exclude these folders from being copied to your build directory.

Answer (score -1):

use this config:

```
keepBuildDir: true,
```

this can keep output dir

detail: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L70