# Require.js optimizer supposed to copy all files over into the output directory?

Tags: requirejs, r.js

I am trying to integrate the r.js optimizer on the server side ([Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org)) and face one problem: when resolving modules it always looks them up under the **output directory** (`dir`), **not from within the source directory** (`baseUrl` or `appDir`), doesn't find them and thus fails.

#### /project/build.js

```
({
    name: "modules/main",
    dir: "/target",
    baseUrl: "/sources"
})
```

If you wonder, the root path `/` is inside the server's JCR repository, not a file system. Also I simplified the example a bit (hopefully without concealing the issue).

It will resolve and read the main file properly:

#### /sources/modules/main.js

```
require(["modules/foo"]);
```

However, when it now tries to resolve `modules/foo`, it tries to read it from `/target/modules/foo.js` instead of `/sources/modules/foo.js` as I would expect, which does not exist and the whole r.js execution fails and stops.

I tried using `appDir` and all kinds of combinations, but the issue is always the same. I am fairly sure it is not related to my integration code... AFAIU from documentation and googling around, it should either [copy them to the target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897286) before building the optimized file or simply pick them up from the source directory automatically.

- Am I supposed to copy all the raw source files to `/target` myself before running r.js?
- Maybe the problem is that `baseUrl=/overlay` is different from build.js residing inside `/project`?
- Maybe r.js also looks at the current working directory of the r.js process (which is so far undefined in my case)?
- Can the output directory (`dir`) live outside `appDir` or `baseUrl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering myself: I got it to work with the **single output file** approach using `out` instead of `appDir` or `dir`:

```
({
    name: "modules/main",
    baseUrl: "/sources"
    out: "/target/out.js",
})
```

In this case it reads all the modules from the sources and creates a `/target/out-temp.js` which it then moves to `/target/out.js` when done.

This seems to suit my needs so far.

Comment: Hey Alexander, did you ever manage to make this work with modules, I've ran into the same issue you described above but in my case I want it to work with modules otherwise I would have a bunch of config scripts for a multipage site

Comment: No, the single concatenated output file was fine for my case. I define one config file per output anyway.

Answer (score 3):

My require.js configuration looks like so:

```
({
  appDir: "../app",
  baseUrl: "js/lib", // means the base URL is ../app/js/lib
  dir: "../app-built", //target

  // offtopic, but a very handy option
  mainConfigFile: "../app/config.js",

  // I'm not 100% sure if it's equivalent to your version
  // where you're not using "modules" and just "name"
  modules: [{
    name: "../some/main" // this is ../app/js/some/main.js
  }]
})
```

Reading through https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L15 - it seems you do want an appDir specified if you want the files to be copied to the target dir before optimization.

To answer your other questions

- you don't need to manually copy files over
- baseUrl should point to the same place as baseUrl used in your app's config - however you have to adjust it depending on what appDir you choose to use (e.g. appDir="../app" and baseUrl="js/lib", or appDir="../app/js" then baseUrl="lib", etc.)
- appDir and dir should be relative to the build config file - I don't know what happens when you use absolute paths
- yes - output dir does (has to?) live outside appDir. BaseURL is within the appDir/dir (all these names are really confusing..)

I would say

1. use the "appDir" setting
2. try using "modules" like I did instead of just "name"
3. make "appDir" and "dir" relative paths to the build file if you can - these absolute paths might be what's breaking? because other than that the config looks very similar to the one I use

I know there's a different way of configuring it where your output is 1 file, which case the files are read from the source dir - but I haven't used that much myself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I played around with the `appDir` (both absolute or relative), but it never tries to copy all files over. What I see by debug logs I hooked into the file access functions is: **a)** reads the `build.js` file **b)** deletes the `dir` (fresh start) **c)** copies the main file from its source to the output dir **d)** reads and parses the main file from the output dir and **e)** tries to look up the `foo` dependency from inside the output dir, not the source (fails of course). I am missing the initial copy-recursive step (if that's what `appDir` is supposed to do).

Comment: I also tried using `modules` instead of just `main`, to no avail :( I'll keep digging around, your answer at least gives me an idea what is expected.

Comment: I got the "way of configuring it where your output is 1 file" to work, simply using `out`. See my own answer.